# MySQL NDB Installer won't start (webserver already running)

Tags: installation, ndbcluster

I have encountered an odd error where I accidentally closed the shell that was running the python script that launched the installer for NDB cluster.  The site stopped working, however, when I try to relaunch it, I'm told that the webserver is already running, but I can not connect to the installer.

How can I get the NDB installer functioning again?  I am running a set of Linux lightsail instances and the most recent GA release of community NDB server.

Comment: Can't you "reboot" that instance?  Else, go looking for the hanging installation with "ps -ef", and kill it.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - yes, however it still says it's running after a reboot and I don't see it in ps (or at least if it's in there, it isn't anything I recognize as a web server).